# WooCommerce Shipping Methods not Appearing for Non Logged Users

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm appealing to your expertise.. I've searched and searched and nothing came up. As a logged in user I'm getting all the shipping methods, as non-logged user I'm not seeing any and the purchases are going through.

Has anyone experienced this?

I've tried disabling plugins and changing to twentyninteen theme and it's still happening.

Thanks a mil

j

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27214584#) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For none-related code questions visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. For those who are experiencing this I recommend activation the shipping debug mode (WC > Settings > Shipping), saving changes and refreshing the checkout.